# Django filter related objects use ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

Imagine that, I have A Model and B Model.

```
Class A (models.Model):
 a_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

Class B (models.Model):
 b_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 a_name = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field="a_name", db_column="a_name")
```

Then, I want to get A , and every A will have all related B

```
A.filter(a_name="a_name").all()
```

But I also want to filter B by b_name when I get the A result above, How can I do that?

Comment: Please show sample data and desired result.

Comment: Where do you get the value of `b_name`?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is reverse query a model ForeignKey relationship. So from the parent class to the child class.
Try this:

```
# Access the A obj you want to query 
a_obj = A.objects.filter(a_name = a_name)

# Query the related B obj's of the above A obj
# filtered by a specifc B obj name
# you can achieve this by calling _set on the child class (B)
# .ie. parentmodel.childmodel_set
b_obj = a_obj.b_set.filter(b_name=b_name)
```

Note: 
When calling _set the model name is written in lowercase .i.e b instead of B.